# Making minor edits elsewhere while working on a commit

Tags: version-control, development-process

I have a habit of constantly making minor edits to my code whenever I spot something I don't like - be it a bug or just some sloppy piece of code I see how to improve. Neurosis-Driven Development.

The problem is this habit doesn't work well with VCS. I can be working on a new function and, by the time I finish it, I have 10 unrelated edits in different parts of the code (usually in the same file). I am left with three options:

- Every time I want to make a minor edit, switch to `work` branch, commit the progress, switch to `master`, make the minor change, commit, switch back to `work`.
- Feel free to edit as much as I want, then commit everything together. But mixing conceptually different edits in one commit is a bad practice.
- Same as above, but when the time comes for the big commit, try to disentangle the edits with tools like `git add --patch` and commit them separately

Any of these options makes me want to give up on VCS whatsoever. Is there a fourth option I don't see or is one of the above not as bad as it sounds?

Comment: see also: [Is it worth making a commit solely to resolve non-critical typos?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156266/is-it-worth-making-a-commit-solely-to-resolve-non-critical-typos)

Answer (score 5):

Use `git add --patch` right after you make the change. Make many small commits whenever you have a meaningful step. Later you can rebase and squash related commits together. It's far easier to use rebase to merge multiple commits into one than it is to split one diff to multiple commits.

Comment: I agree, but: I would not squash all commits together in the end. New implementations and changes should be separate commits from drive-by changes (they should be marked with a clear naming scheme, IMO). There are two reason not squashing "live" changes with drive-by changes: "in the now", if applicable, such a commit is hard to review, in the future it would be harder to understand why a change was made (or what the change actually indended to change)

Comment: @try-catch-finally I don't suggest merging unrelated changes, but if one logical change spans multiple commits (ie, "add a; fix bug with a"), they can be squashed into one commit ("add a").

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do:

1. Remain disciplined, only make the changes which are applicable to the current working branch.
2. Create a branch off of `master` called `MyDevBranch`.
3. Create a branch off of `MyDevBranch` that addresses a specific functionality/feature (`MyFeatureBranch`).
4. Make lots and lots of commits... Each time I finish *part* of a feature that addresses some certain aspect *of* that feature I do a commit to `MyFeatureBranch` (i.e. write a method, or create an unimplemented method stub).
5. When I finish the entire feature, I will merge the `MyFeatureBranch` to the `MyDevBranch`.

This has worked for me so far, when I complete all 5 of these steps I will merge `MyDevBranch` to the `master`. Then `push` my `master` branch up to a *bare* repository on our server, where it merges with the existing `master`.

If you happen to make some changes and you don't want to integrate them right away, you can also `stash` the changes then `pop` them later on.. See [this link here.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Maybe also check out this question somebody asked about stashing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925099/git-stash-changes-apply-to-new-branch).

I was the exact same way as at first, until I read more about Git and asked questions to see what others were doing.